# Problems with comma operator in C

Tags: c

i'm not even sure if comma operator is the problem here but i didn't want to write "*Weird problem with my C code*.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i = 0, x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;

    y = 3;
    z = 5;

    (x&&(y = z), i = 10);

    printf("i:%d, x:%d, y:%d, z:%d\n", x, y, z, i);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with:

```
$ gcc -Wall deneme.c -o deneme
deneme.c: In function ‘main’:
deneme.c:9:4: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
deneme.c:9:4: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
```

and output is:

```
i:0, x:3, y:5, z:10
```

So, here is my questions:

- Why `i` is not 10?
- `y` is 5 and that's okay, but why `z` is 10?
- Why `x` is 3?

---

Sorry if it's an *easy* question but i'm totally confused.

Comment: Why is `y = 5` okay? It's actually 3 (as it should be).

Comment: If you are not asking about the compiler warnings (which perhaps you should), then you should remove them from the question - they are a distraction - many contributors will address that and miss your actual (less interesting) questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
printf("i:%d, x:%d, y:%d, z:%d\n", x, y, z, i);
```

You printed `x` as `i`, `y` as `x`, `z` as `y` and `i` as `z`.

Comment: Which means that in reality, `i = 10`, `x = 0`, `y = 3`, and `z = 5`, which is what the OP expects (or at least should expect).

Comment: @boraalper4: That is perhaps an answer to your questions at the end but not the implied question about the compiler warnings (which arguably are more critical).

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying wrong order of the arguments in the printf

Answer (score 0):

Um... the order of your arguments to the printf doesn't match the text of the string.

Ie: you print i x y z, but you pass in x y z i.

So i=10, x=0, y=3 z= 5.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the warnings is not to do with the the comma operator, but rather this sub-expression: `x && (y = z)` is evaluated but not assigned to anything or used in any way, so the result is discarded.

It does have a side effect that may be intentional by the short circuit evaluation of `x`. i.e. if `x` is zero, `y` will not be assigned `z`, but that would be funky code best avoided.

In fact the comma operator is also best avoided outside of `<expr1>` or `<expr3>` of a `for(  ;  ;  ) construct perhaps. There are few useful or compelling uses for it otherwise.